# IOS methods deprecated before introduced

Tags: ios, deprecated

I'm curious as to why many IOS methods are deprecated before they are introduced.  For example, most of NSString's deprecated methods were available in IOS 4.0 or later but deprecated in IOS 2.0.  Any logic behind this?  Lazy bookkeeping maybe?

It causes some minor issues.  Namely, docset datastore values don't line up with their flat HTML counterparts.

NSString deprecated example:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/initWithCStringNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:

Answer (score 2):

It does look like a bug. I looked in "NSString.h" and found this:

[image]

Then I looked to the source of the `NS_DEPRECATED` macro ("NSObjCRuntime.h") and found this:

[image]

So `stringWithContentsOfFile` was available for iOS use starting with 2.0 and was deprecated in 2.0.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a documentation bug.  Those methods were available in iOS 2.0.